# Weird outline around buttons

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a site, but these weird button outlines are ruining it.

[Button with outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAxvc.png)

I tried using "outline: none;" but that doesn't seem to work!

Comment: try `border-width: 0`

Comment: please read [ask]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

its not `outline` its `border` of button as default, its `border-style: outset;`
you just need to apply this property to all the buttons `border-style:none;`

thank you!